# AWS Forecast. Too few observations for number of items

Tags: r, statistics, amazon-forecast

I am trying to do some tests with Amazon Forecast. I have tried now two different datasets which look like so:

`13,2013-03-31 19:25:00,93.10999
14,2013-03-31 19:35:00,93.5
15,2013-03-31 19:40:00,93.64
16,2013-03-31 19:50:00,93.74
17,2013-03-31 20:00:00,93.8
18,2013-03-31 20:10:00,92.5`

It is:

`id, date, value`

Both of them return back with this error:

`Too few observations (633334) for number of items (633334), averaging 1.000 observations per item`

But with different counts of item.

Forecast is very new so there isn't anything coming up on searches. Documentation talks nothing about this error. Really have no idea where to even start trying to get past this.

Comment: Same error I encountered

Answer (score 7):

You need to identify a unique item in the data set that has multiple observations. The error you got means that none of the item in your dataset has more than 1 observation. To understand better consider this dataset:

```
2014-10-30 18:00:00, 144.2786069651745, client_12
2014-10-30 19:00:00, 139.30348258706476, client_12
2014-10-30 20:00:00, 133.29187396351574, client_12
2014-10-30 21:00:00, 83.95522388059702, client_12
2014-10-30 22:00:00, 60.116086235489256, client_12
2014-10-30 23:00:00, 56.17744610281925, client_12
2014-01-01 01:00:00, 56.07302533532045, client_10
2014-01-01 02:00:00, 48.435171385991076, client_10
2014-01-01 03:00:00, 43.21907600596124, client_10
2014-01-01 04:00:00, 39.1207153502235, client_10
2014-01-01 05:00:00, 37.81669150521605, client_10
2014-01-01 06:00:00, 34.836065573770455, client_10
2014-01-01 07:00:00, 34.6497764530551, client_10
2014-01-01 08:00:00, 30.737704918032748, client_10
2014-01-01 09:00:00, 27.1982116244411, client_10
```

You can see there are three fields, timestamp, target and item. The item i.e. client must have multiple target value observations recorded over a period of time.

To fix the error you need identify an item and the target value. Hope this helps.

Comment: Would love to know what the major number is we need to hit to not get this error..?